# Is there a way to implement Push Notification to Twilio Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to get notified when I'm not in the chat page. But this library does not support.
Is anyone help me to solve this problem, because I cannot find anything.

Push Notification does not exist on this library - twilio_chat_conversation: ^1.0.4 - https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_chat_conversation